# Bootstrap 3 | Como deixar última coluna sempre mais à direita?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, table, tabela-html

Preciso deixar a última coluna da minha tabela (a que tem os *glyphs* de ação) sempre mais à direita:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1"></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>E-mail</td>
      <td>Actions</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar">
          <div role="group" class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" alt="Delete record" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div role="group" class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" alt="Edit record" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" alt="Move record up" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" alt="Move record down" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: tente adicionar a classe `pull-right`

Comment: Coloiquei o `pull-right` no `td` mas a tabela ficou com um espaço sem as bordas.

Comment: Estou no celular, e não da para colocar um exemplo. Mar você já tentou adicionar uma **div align=center** no conteúdo.

Comment: Ou um td **align right**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dito nos comentário, basta colocar um `pull-right`, mas não na coluna, e sim na `div` que terá a barra de botões, como este exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1"></td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>E-mail</td>
      <td><span class="pull-right">Actions</span></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>John Doe</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>johndoe@example.com</td>
      <td>
        <div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
          <div role="group" class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" alt="Delete record" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div role="group" class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" alt="Edit record" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" alt="Move record up" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" alt="Move record down" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tive que adicionar um `pull-right` na `div` com o `btn-group` e adicionar as classes `pull-right` e `text-right` no cabeçalho da tabela. Pensei que tivesse alguma outra maneira de fazer isso. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: @chorajunior alterei a forma de alinhamento no cabeçalho também, utilizando um `span`, daí alinhamos apenas ele. Nas `div` com estilos `btn-group` não é necessário neste exemplo, apenas na `div` externa. Neste caso e com bootstrap não conheço outra forma.