# Organizando elementos no cabeçalho do bootstrap panel

Tags: css, bootstrap-3

**Exemplo**

```html
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title  pull-left"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" style="font-size:20px;width:30px;"></i> Eventos Vinculados</h3>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="FiltroTabela" placeholder="Buscar..." style="width:300px" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="novoEvento()"><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></span> Novo </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Para alinhar o título na esquerda utilizei o `panel-title  pull-left` mas no casos em serão usados [input-groups](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups) e [btn-groups](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups) qual seria o código para definir alinhamento dos elementos para direita ?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Bootstrap 3 | Como deixar última coluna sempre mais à direita?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83308/bootstrap-3-como-deixar-%c3%baltima-coluna-sempre-mais-%c3%a0-direita)

Comment: Vou ver se consigo elaborar melhor por além de jogar para direita tenho que saber qual o formato de agrupamento seria mais adequado usar para este caso.